# Having issues with having a program re-run

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a program that will ask the user to guess a random number 6 times. The program has to ask if they want to play again and will keep a running total of the wins/losses. 
How would I have the program rerun?

heres the code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Project {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

String input;
double guess = 0;
int number;
double wins = 0;
double losses = 0;
String repeat;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  Random randomNumbers = new Random();

System.out.println("Welcome to Higher/Lower!");

System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
input = keyboard.nextLine();

while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")); {
  number = randomNumbers.nextInt(100) + 1;
  System.out.println("I've chosen my number, " + input + "You only have 6 tries, good luck!"); }

  for(int num = 1; number != guess && number <= 6; num++) {
    System.out.println("Enter guess " + num + ":");
    guess = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if(guess < number)
      System.out.println("higher.");
    else if(guess > number)
      System.out.println("lower.");
    else
      System.out.println("Congratulations!"); }

                           if(guess == number)    {
      System.out.println("You guesses my number!"); wins++; }
                           if(guess != number) {
                           System.out.println("Sorry, " + input + " my number was " + number +
                                              "You lose!"); losses++; }

                         System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (Yes/No): ");
                         repeat = keyboard.nextLine();

                         if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")); {
                           System.out.println("Thanks for playing!"); }

                           System.out.println(wins + " wins");
                           System.out.println(losses + " losses");
                         }
}
```

It is skipping over asking me if i want to play again or not and i dont know what kind of loop to use

Comment: With a loop, but since you tagged that in your question, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: i added the code to my post

Answer (score 0):

Wihtout your code, I'm assuming this is what you need.

```
boolean doContinue = true;
do {
     //guess random number 6 times
     //do you want to continue?
     // yes -> doContinue = true;
     // no -> doContinue = false;
} while (doContinue );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making your loop a do-while loop like this:

```
do {
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
        /*
            insert code for the guessing/checking/etc.
        */
    }
    System.out.print("Would you like to continue? [Y/n] ");
} while (scan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0) != 'Y');
```